# How do I get Python distutils to honor $CC?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, distutils

I am trying to use the ccomppiler functionality in Python distutils to compile & execute a test program.  So far I have:

```
from distutils import ccompiler
cc = ccompiler.new_compiler()
outfiles = cc.compile(['detect.c'])
cc.link_executable(outfiles, 'detect')
output = subprocess.check_output(['./detect']).decode('ascii')
```

This all works fine.  However, unlike when running distutils via setup.py "setup()", the default compiler is used `gcc -pthread`, rather than the setting in the environment variable `CC`.  How can I get this compiler to use the setting from `CC`?

Things I have tried without success:

- `cc.set_executable` and `cc.set_executables`, although I can't really tell what they do or how to use them from the documentation
- manually changing `cc.compiler`; no effect
- looking in `distutils.sysconfig`; there are lots of ways to get config variables, but no way to set anything!